# jsp net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: spring, google-chrome, jsp, tomcat

My Spring web is facing with `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` in chrome

> Environment:
>
> - Client: Chrome 54 (latest)
> - Server: CentOS 7, Tomcat 9.0.0.M11
> - Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE

Web app WAS OK. But after I added a filter to add Cache-Control, after some days, this problem came with me in Chrome ONLY:

> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING .... example.com/js/bundle.js

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

As you see, I made a cache filter for js and css-es and problem came with all of them.

Current tomcat configuration:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    useSendfile="false"
    compression="on" 
    compressionMinSize="2048" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml, application/javascript, text/css"
/>
```

After I removed the filter, the problem gone, but this is just a temporary fix.

Any better solution?

Thanks for read.

---

Some more research:

- I am not using any antivirus
- I am not using any adblock
- I am not using any chrome extension